# How do I correctly add a Seaborn hue to my graph?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have a very simple dataframe of two people:

And I want to plot this with the correct hue, so a legend is generated

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {"John":[43, 23, 12], "Mary":[24, 53, 32],"Trial_#":[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
fig = sns.pointplot(x='Trial_#', y='John',
data = df)
fig = sns.pointplot(x='Trial_#', y='Mary',
data = df)

sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1)
fig.set(ylabel="Guess")
fig.set(xlabel="Trial")
plt.show()
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using `matplotlib` as an alternative to the `seaborn`'s `pointplot`, you can simply do the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
d = {"John":[43, 23, 12], "Mary":[24, 53, 32],"Trial_#":[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

ax.plot(df['Trial_#'], df['John'], '-ro', label="John")
ax.plot(df['Trial_#'], df['Mary'], '-go',  label="Mary")

ax.set(ylabel="Guess")
ax.set(xlabel="Trial")
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Thats helpful, but i prefer a seaborn solution if that exists.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using matplotlib

The key would be to set the index to the trial number column, such that the remaining columns contain the values to be plotted. Then the dataframe can directly be supplied to matplotlib's `plot` function. A little drawback is that the legend needs to created individually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {"John":[43, 23, 12], "Mary":[24, 53, 32], "Trial_#":[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.set_index("Trial_#")
                       
lines = plt.plot(df, marker="o")
plt.ylabel("Guess")
plt.legend(lines, df.columns)

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using pandas

You can directly plot with pandas, which has the advantage of giving you a legend for free.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {"John":[43, 23, 12], "Mary":[24, 53, 32], "Trial_#":[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
                           
ax = df.set_index("Trial_#").plot(marker="o")
ax.set(ylabel="Guess")

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Using Seaborn

The most complicated solution is with Seaborn. Seaborn works with long-form dataframes. To convert a wide-form dataframe to a long form dataframe you can use `pandas.melt`. The resulting long-form frame then contains a column with the names in it; those can be used as `hue` variable in seaborn.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

d = {"John":[43, 23, 12], "Mary":[24, 53, 32], "Trial_#":[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
                           
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Trial_#'], value_vars=['John', 'Mary'], 
                  var_name="Name", value_name="Guess")
ax = sns.pointplot(x='Trial_#', y='Guess', hue="Name", data = dfm)

plt.show()
```

[image]